# GCP create function zip upload error without description

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a simple GCP Cloud Function via GCP console but the zip upload fails every time without a detailed reason:

the zip file includes the source files (and not a file with the source files).
in that way, the function isn't being created. I've tried to search online but couldn't find an answer.

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omY26.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more context to your question so that we may help answer it. Are you following a specific tutorial? Which language|runtime are you using? What exactly did you do that got you to that error? It appears that you're using the Cloud Console for Cloud Functions and attempting to create the function by uploading zipped sources. If so, you can switch to "Inline Editor" for your language to get a better sense of what it's expecting. The tutorials are good too... Perhaps start with one of those and see what zip file it produces to compare with what you have.

Comment: Clarity is needed, not sure what your asking here